# How to modify output shape of custom recurrent layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I want to write a custom LSTM layer in Keras where I want to modify `cell states`. I suppose I need to specify the shape of states using the method `compute_output_shape`. However, when I try to change the output shape, nothing happens.

The following code alters the output shape to a wrong value. I will expect the code to give me the error but it is running file.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, LSTMCell, Input, RNN
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


class HRU_LSTMCell(LSTM):

    def __init__(self,
                 no_of_hrus=None,
                 **kwargs):

        super(HRU_LSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.no_of_hrus = no_of_hrus


    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(HRU_LSTMCell, self).build(input_shape)


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        print('calculating output shape')
        return -99 


# define model
inputs1 = Input(shape=(10, 3))
lstm1 = HRU_LSTMCell(units=5, return_state=True)(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)

# check output
h1, h2, c = model.predict(data)

print(h1.shape, h2.shape, c.shape)
```

What I am missing

Comment: Have a got a solution of your problem?